# DataStage Client 8.5 Installation Error on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, sql

I am trying to install Datastage Client 8.5 on Windows 7 x64 and getting the below error:

```
com.ibm.is.install.exception.ActionException: CDIIN5032E: Exception caught by ExecuteProcessAction.:

CDIIN5106I: Details:
InstallAction (_id = install.xmeta.client, _installUnitModelId = ISFNode)
```

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error derives from the fact that a component cannot install because another component does not exist. The component location is

`c:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Temp\ibm_is_test_datestamp\xmeta\client\bin`

The install program cannot write a new `\xmeta\client\bin` because it believes there is one there already.

To resolve this you have to delete all occurrences of any previous installs. So before you run another install:

1. Delete `\IBM\InformationServer` folder
2. Delete entries in the registry.

   1. If you have Windows 7 then click on windows icon then click on *Run...*
   2. Type `regedit` which will open up the registry
   3. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\` then delete the `\IBM` folder which will delete all the subfolders.
   4. Next locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` then delete `\IBM` folder which will delete all the subfolders.
3. This is optional but I restarted the server.
4. This allows you to perform a complete client install.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error today and after several tests I found that the error depends on the directory where 'is-client' is for installing IIS.

With `c:\$user` the error appears but from `c:\temp`, installation worked fine.